# python cx_Oracle crazy tuple

Tags: python, cx-oracle

result:
[('192.168.200.10',), ('192.168.200.11',), ('192.168.200.12',), ('192.168.200.13',), ('192.168.50.2',), ('192.168.50.70',), ('192.168.50.9',)]
1

```
import cx_Oracle
con = cx_Oracle.connect('something')
cur = con.cursor()
cur.execute("something")
tab = []
for a in cur:
    tab.append(a)
print(tab)
print(len(tab[1]))
cur.close()
con.close()
```

i want to make this to tab of clean ip like
   ["192.168.200.10","192.168.200.11"]
and i have a question here, why the length of tab[1] is 1?

Comment: Because the tuple has just on element (the ip string).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try using this

```
result = [row[0] for row in tab]
```

Output

> ['192.168.200.10',
>    '192.168.200.11',
>    '192.168.200.12',
>    '192.168.200.13',
>    '192.168.50.2',
>    '192.168.50.70',
>    '192.168.50.9']

Or you can change the way you append your result to `tab` list. Like this

```
for a in cur:
    tab.append(a[0])
```

For your length = 1 question. It is because there is only one ip inside the tuple. hence you get the length as 1